# How can I define a method which arguments have no type in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, dsl

If I defined a method:

```
def weird_method(first_argument, second_argument)
  #code here
end
```

so this way I can pass arguments like : 1, :digit, 'some', "more"(Fixnum, Symbol, String etc.) , BUT what If I wanted to pass just this: **argument1, argument2** , I mean values that have no type and look like local variables but they actually are not. How can I accept them somehow and use them in the method body?

PS: I need it for implementing a small DSL that could do that kind of stuff in the **.isntance_eval** when blok is passed

```
Something.with_method do
 sum 1, 2         #(I can implement it)
 play volleyball  #(I can NOT implement it)
 swim further     #(I can NOT implement it)
 eat "a lot"      #(I can implement it)
end
```

**EDIT:**

Everything could go on the palce of **volleyball** and **further**. I am just gave an example. sum, play, swim, eat are methods defined in the Something class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a value without type, what would `volleyball` be in your example? Method? Variable?

Comment: If you want to pass the *name* of another variable or method, then it is common to use a `String` or `Symbol`, because these can be used with `eval`, `define_method` and other Ruby meta-programming methods.

Comment: @mechanicalfish sum, play, swin, eat are all methods in my Something. The argument is the issue.

Comment: The method looks weird for me

Answer (score 2):

Symbols exist for exactly the purpose you're talking about here: They're values that just evaluate to themselves. The symbol `:volleyball` is the symbol `:volleyball` and that is all it will ever be. It has no other value or meaning.

If you just want it to read differently for aesthetic purposes, your best bet would probably be to define methods that return the appropriate symbol (e.g. `def volleyball() :volleyball end`). But this seems unidiomatic.

If you really want people to be able to send just about anything that isn't already a method, you could implement a `method_missing` along the lines of `def method_missing(m, *args) m.to_sym end`. But I really find this design awkward in most contexts I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Something
  attr_reader :callstack

  def initialize
    @callstack = {}
  end

  def self.with_method &block
   self.new.instance_exec &block
  end

  def method_missing method, *params
    params.empty? ? method : callstack[method] = params
  end
end

Something.with_method do
 sum 1, 2
 play volleyball
 swim further
 eat "a lot"

 puts callstack # => {:sum=>[1, 2], :play=>[:volleyball], :swim=>[:further], :eat=>["a lot"]}
end
```

Does this help?

Comment: See, volleyball and further are just for the example. Your logics says that I can only pass volleyball and further. What if I wanted to pass: footbal, softball, baseball etc to the play method? Everything could go on the play method argument

Comment: I've updated the answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, this is not the callstack. Plus when I started your code it only accepts the arguments for sum and eat. play and swim seem to be 'argumentless'.

Comment: It is and they're not argumentless. `volleyball` and `further` are the arguments here. I recommend rethinking your problem, because obviously you don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: That's very good stanza. Do you know how to implement *constants*? For example `Something.with_method do; Meth1; call Me; callstack; end` will raise an error because `Meth1` and `Me` are not defined in the `Something` class. Moreover both `Meth1` & `Me` are considered constants because they start with capital letter and have no argument(s). They will be send to the `Object`'s class method `const_missing`. How to above example work without changing `Object`?

Comment: Good question. I'd try with refinements or rescuing `NameError`.

Comment: 2nd options seems good(as I'm on 1.9.3). Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You must pass objects as method arguments. What functionality are you trying to accomplish by passing arbitrary non-defined names? You could always pass them as a string and then use the string to use the text inside the method.

ex.

```
def self.methodname(arg1, arg2)
  arg1 = arg2
end

Class.methodname("greeting","hello")
```

would set the variable greeting equal to `'hello'`

Comment: Sam, you need to format the code in your answer.  Either highlight it and click on the {} icon or surround the code with backticks (the back-slanting single quote, located in the upper left corner of my Mac keyboard).  (Much better!)

Comment: Its idea is to implement a simple assembler working with only 4 registers and at some point i could put labels, jump to commands in the code but it is hard to explain it. I just need to be able to accept the arguments if they were passed like this.