# How to achieve this Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby

I saw the following code yesterday (in the [fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem)

How can I write something like this? (I'm answering my own question below but feel free to suggest edits or other ways to solve this problem :-) )

Note that "slow", "also_slow" and the other methods called below do not exist:

```
require 'fruity'
compare do
  slow      { sleep(0.06) }
  also_slow { sleep(0.03); sleep(0.03) }
  quick     { sleep(0.03) }
  quicker   { sleep(0.01) }
end
```

Comment: Why the downvote? SO suggests we can ask and answer our own questions.

Comment: I don't think it is beautiful. `slow`, etc. are used as labels, which should be naturally written as strings or symbols. (-1 is not from me, and this is not a response to your comment above. Although, I agree that the question is not good. The point seems to be how to use undefined methods on the spot; it has nothing to do with beauty. There are too many irrelevant things in the question.)

Comment: @sawa, I agree it can be confusing at first but I think it makes sense with benchmarking as fruity uses it, no?

Comment: Got rid of my "feelings" in the question =)

Comment: Well, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080780/how-can-i-define-a-method-which-arguments-have-no-type-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it has to do with `method_missing` but wanted to write something like it for the purpose of learning.

In order to achieve this, we need two things:

1. an object with `method_missing` where we'll be calling the block because we don't want to have a global `method_missing` handling the methods (think about slow, also_slow, etc, being called on the object)
2. a method similar to the compare method above that would call `instance_eval` for the block on the object

Below goes the code:

```
require 'benchmark'

# the class which instance will be evaluating our missing methods
class BlockEvaluator
  attr_accessor :hashy

  def initialize
    @hashy = {}
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    # collect missing methods' names into hash with the (inner) block of code passed to it
    # i.e. { sleep(0.06} }
    @hashy[m.to_s] = block if block_given?
  end
end

# the method that will be calling the passed block on an instance of BlockEvaluator
def measure_stuff(&block)
  be = BlockEvaluator.new
  be.instance_eval(&block)

  measurements = {}

  # get the length of the longest method name (slow, also_slow, etc) in order to pad accordingly
  maxlen = be.hashy.keys.map(&:length).max

  be.hashy.each do |k,v|
    puts "#{k.rjust(maxlen)}#{Benchmark.measure(&v).to_s.chomp}"
  end

  nil
end

arr = (1..10_000).to_a
# here goes my own
measure_stuff do
  zip { 100.times { arr.zip([nil]) } }
  product { 100.times { arr.product([nil]) } }
end
```

Comment: Keep in mind that stuffs in block are evaluated too. `class BlockEvaluator;
  def sleep n;
    puts "sleep in blockevaluator";
  end;
end;

measure_stuff do;
  hello {sleep(2)};
end`, here `sleep` is not `Kernel#sleep` but `BlockEvaluator#sleep`. ps. check comment to the question. It contains very interesting answer.

Comment: Yup, thanks for mentioning this as someone might be wondering why their method is not being called :-) -- mind telling me which comment are you referring to?

Comment: To my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606023/how-to-achieve-this-ruby-syntax/21606024?noredirect=1#comment32647548_21606023

Comment: My bad.. I saw your comment and the answers as well... I wanted to see which answer you found interesting =)

Comment: Ah, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21080882/2597260 (check comments to this answer as well, as I have little talk with author)